# Clang partial class template specialization error

Tags: c++, g++, c++20, clang++, template-specialization

I've the following simple c++20 test:

```
#include <type_traits>
/////////////////////////////////////// constraints

template <typename Type> concept isConst = ::std::is_const_v<Type>;

template <typename Type> concept isNotConst = !isConst<Type>;

/////////////////////////////////////// class decleration

template <typename T>
class TestRef;

template <isNotConst T>
struct TestRef<T> {
    explicit TestRef(T& value) noexcept;
};

template <isConst T>
struct TestRef<T> {
    explicit TestRef(T& value) noexcept;
};

/////////////////////////////////////// class implementation

template <isNotConst T>
TestRef<T>::TestRef(T& value) noexcept {}

template <isConst T>
TestRef<T>::TestRef(T& value) noexcept {}

/////////////////////////////////////// main

int main()
{
    int a{ 1 };
    TestRef<int> ref1{ a };
    TestRef<const int> ref2{ a };
    return 0;
}
```

This exemple compiles fine with g++ 12.2.0. However, using clang++ 14.0.6, it does not. Here is the error:

```
error: incomplete type 'TestRef' named in nested name specifier
```

I failed to identify the reason why it does and how to work around it.

What I understood is that it does not choose the specialized structure. It uses the basic one that is not defined.

If I do define it, I get the error:

```
error: type constraint differs in template redeclaration
```

What can I do to fix the issue?

Comment: Only gcc accepts the code while both clang and msvc rejects it. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1oW953so5)

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mension that it is in c++20

Comment: Yes, since you're using concepts it must be c++20 or greater.

Comment: I always turn on c++23 so I never know what feature is from what version.
Do you have any idea how I can fix that on, at least, clang?

Comment: The simplest way to solve this would be to define the constructors inside instead of giving the out of class definition. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jsnnrzf7r). Btw, gcc is correct in accepting the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no reason that you must use concepts, you can use a pre-C++20 way to implement it.

```cpp
template <typename T, typename = void>
class TestRef;

template <typename T>
struct TestRef<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_const_v<T>>> {
    explicit TestRef(T& value) noexcept;
};

template <typename T>
struct TestRef<T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_const_v<T>>> {
    explicit TestRef(T& value) noexcept;
};

/////////////////////////////////////// class implementation

template <typename T>
TestRef<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_const_v<T>>>::TestRef(T& value) noexcept {}

template <typename T>
TestRef<T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_const_v<T>>>::TestRef(T& value) noexcept {}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aTW8Kovv9)

I'm showing you a general way. In your case, you don't have another specialization for the non-const version. You can fill them in the primary template.

Comment: Aren't concepts made to replace enable_if?

Comment: In this case, concepts behave more concisely, but the problem here is the compiler doesn't pass...lol

Comment: As signatures are identical, `if constexpr` might be simpler.

Answer (score 2):

> I failed to identify the reason why it does

**GCC is correct in accepting** the given code as the program is well-formed. Here is a similar [clang bug report](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51301).

> What can I do to fix the issue?

Since **clang and msvc are wrong in rejecting the code** here, the *simplest way* to make the program work with all compilers is to simply provide the definitions for the constructors inside the class template as shown below:

```
template <isNotConst T>
struct TestRef<T> {
    //implement inside instead of out of class definition
    explicit TestRef(T& value) noexcept
    {

    }
};

template <isConst T>
struct TestRef<T> {
    //implement inside instead of out of class definition
    explicit TestRef(T& value) noexcept
    {

    }
};
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jsnnrzf7r)

Comment: Is this really the only way?

Comment: @DiantArts It's the simplest way(as also said in my answer) that i would personally use for this example.

Comment: I agree that this is a simple way. However, I would prefer another way since this is kinda hard to keep in a bigger scale project

Comment: @DiantArts I see, unfortunately i don't have an alternative way. After searching clang bugs, i found [this old clang bug report](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51301) that might be helpful/related here.